# Find programs which are using a special file

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, filesystems, task-manager

I want to delete a file but it cannot be deleted because is used by another program. how can I find the program which is using this file? I've seen task manager but there is nothing there to find out it!

I'm using windows 7.

Comment: More details are needed. This question is too vague to be able to help you. What is the name of the file? If you don't know what it is, why are you trying to delete it?

Comment: Also see: https://superuser.com/questions/443938/file-locked-read-only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use **lockhunter** (http://lockhunter.com/) or 
**unlocker** (http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/).
Both programs can show which process is accessing the file you want to delete.

**EDIT:**
Even if the tools are self-explaining, here is what you need to do:
Just install one of these tools. When trying to delete a file which is in use, the tool will popup a window with Locking-Informations. Or **right-click** on the file (you want to delete) and choose (from context-menu) **unlock**.

Comment: Can you please explain how to use the software in a way that solves the OP's question?